# How to get pg_escape_literal on PHP 5.3?

Tags: php, postgresql

I am developing some project, where I have postgre database. PHP is 5.3 (cannot be updated, because it is quite big webpage), so pg_escape_literal is not supported. I google everything about it, but didn't find anything interesting - couldn't find some PHP escape_literal function. I also tried pg_escape_string, but as far as I tested it, it doesn't work (when I printed whole string, escaped by pg_escape_string, it shows some slashes, which broke sql statement, and any removal with functions didn't work).

EDIT: I found this, but I don't know if this is really just what escape_literal does - 
https://searchcode.com/codesearch/view/11003494/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`pg_escape_literal($dbcnx, $string)` should be equivalent to:

```
 "'" . pg_escape_string($dbcnx, $string) . "'"
```